# Why does scrapy miss some links?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am scraping the web-site "www.accell-group.com" using the "scrapy" library for Python. The site is scraped completely, in total 131 pages (text/html) and 2 documents (application/pdf) are identified. Scrapy did not throw any warnings or errors. My algorithm is supposed to scrape every single link. I use CrawlSpider.

However, when I look into the page "http://www.accell-group.com/nl/investor-relations/jaarverslagen/jaarverslagen-van-accell-group.htm", which is reported by "scrapy" as scraped/processed, I see that there are more pdf-documents, for example "http://www.accell-group.com/files/4/5/0/1/Jaarverslag2014.pdf". I cannot find any reasons for it not to be scraped. There is no dynamic/JavaScript content on this page. It is not forbidden in "http://www.airproducts.com/robots.txt".

Do you maybe have any idea why it can happen?
It is maybe because the "files" folder is not in "http://www.accell-group.com/sitemap.xml"?

Thanks in advance!

My code:

```
class PyscrappSpider(CrawlSpider):
    """This is the Pyscrapp spider"""
    name = "PyscrappSpider"

    def__init__(self, *a, **kw):

        # Get the passed URL
        originalURL =  kw.get('originalURL')
        logger.debug('Original url = {}'.format(originalURL))

        # Add a protocol, if needed
        startURL = 'http://{}/'.format(originalURL)
        self.start_urls = [startURL]

        self.in_redirect = {}
        self.allowed_domains = [urlparse(i).hostname.strip() for i in self.start_urls]
        self.pattern = r""
        self.rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=[r"accessdenied"]), callback="parse_data", follow=True), )

        # Get WARC writer        
        self.warcHandler = kw.get('warcHandler')

        # Initialise the base constructor
        super(PyscrappSpider, self).__init__(*a, **kw)


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        if (response.request.meta.has_key("redirect_urls")):
            original_url = response.request.meta["redirect_urls"][0]
            if ((not self.in_redirect.has_key(original_url)) or (not self.in_redirect[original_url])):
                self.in_redirect[original_url] = True
                self.allowed_domains.append(original_url)
        return self.parse_data(response)

    def parse_data(self, response):

        """This function extracts data from the page."""

        self.warcHandler.write_response(response)

        pattern = self.pattern

        # Check if we are interested in the current page
        if (not response.request.headers.get('Referer') 
            or re.search(pattern, self.ensure_not_null(response.meta.get('link_text')), re.IGNORECASE) 
            or re.search(r"/(" + pattern + r")", self.ensure_not_null(response.url), re.IGNORECASE)):

            logging.debug("This page gets processed = %(url)s", {'url': response.url})

            sel = Selector(response)

            item = PyscrappItem()
            item['url'] = response.url


            return item
        else:

            logging.warning("This page does NOT get processed = %(url)s", {'url': response.url})
            return response.request
```

Comment: _"My algorithm is supposed to scrape every single link. I use CrawlSpider."_ Can you post relevant parts of your spider?

Comment: Only text/html files can be scraped, pdf files have to be downloaded, doubt that scrapy can handle them

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida Scrapy is happy to download pdf files or image files.

Comment: @Paul Trmbrth: Posted.

Answer (score 2):

Remove or expand appropriately your "allowed_domains" variable and you should be fine. All the URLs the spider follows, by default, are restricted by allowed_domains.

EDIT: This case mentions particularly pdfs. PDFs are explicitly excluded as extensions as per the default value of `deny_extensions` (see [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml)) which is `IGNORED_EXTENSIONS` (see [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/linkextractors/__init__.py#L20)).

To allow your application to crawl PDFs all you have to do is to exclude them from `IGNORED_EXTENSIONS` by setting explicitly the value for `deny_extensions`:

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import IGNORED_EXTENSIONS

self.rules = (Rule(...

LinkExtractor(deny=[r"accessdenied"], deny_extensions=set(IGNORED_EXTENSIONS)-set(['pdf']))

..., callback="parse_data"...
```

So, I'm afraid, this is the answer to the question "Why does Scrapy miss some links?". As you will likely see it just opens the doors to further questions, like "how do I handle those PDFs" but I guess this is the subject of another question.

Comment: The link that is missing is from the same domain "www.accell-group.com".

Comment: This answer isn't safe even with very strict rules to a CrawlSpider

Comment: In what sense it isn't "safe"? If it's fine for finding if your alowed_domains is the problem. Yes... Don't run this unless you can Ctrl+C to stop the crawl.

Comment: Now that you provided your code, I get the feeling it gets unnecessarily complex but this is off-topic. I still think there's something weird going on around allowed_domains. I can see you populate it using something like:         'urlparse(i).hostname.strip()'. Debug-log this. Does it give what you expect? Does it include 'www.'? Then, in your second function you append plain urls in it. Debug-print them... Is this what you want? Also notice that if you "expand" allowed_domains from a parse() method this won't affect current page since links have been extracted before calling your parse()

Comment: Actually as far as I can see here... https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py Changing allowed_domains after the spider is opened has no effect.

Comment: @neverlash: The domain that goes to the allowed_domains is ""ww.accell-group.com". I take it from the database. Therefore, the missing links shall be scraped.

Comment: @EkaterinaErmilova - Yes, sorry - didn't have access to fast internet but now that I'm back and had a better look to this case, I see that you're absolutely right. I updated the answer.

Comment: @neverlash: Thanks a lot!!! I have to double-check it now. Because I am actually able to scrape some PDFs and only some of them get ignored. Thus, I need to find the reason why the scraped ones are scraped in spite of "deny_exceptions".

Comment: Great! Hmmm... my guess is that they weren't links ending with `.pdf` but something else but they were returning pdf files.

Comment: @neverlash: I removed PDF from deny_exceptions, and... it WORKED!!! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Awesome. That's great!